# Execute a couple of js functions in order when some of the function hava a couple of ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

I'm trying to create a set of `function` (like App object below) that accepts preInit, Init, Load functions and executes them in order.
For example:

```
var formOperation = App.preInit(function(){
//Some Code ...
})
.init(function(){
//Some Code Here...
})
.load(function(){
//Other Code Here...
});
```

The problem is that I don't  want the users deal with Deferred objects at all and I want them to use as many as `ajax calls` as they want. I don't want them to use functions that are extended to `jQuery like ajaxQueue`.

The only way I could think of is that to get the list of `$.ajax calls` and set Deferred object in them before calling them.

Do you have any idea how I can get the list of `ajax calls` in a `function` before calling the function?
Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to tell (programmatically) if a function passed to your code as a parameter does any Ajax. Even if you could examine that function somehow, it might call other functions that in turn do Ajax things...

Comment: Well I think I've found a solution on this. but the problem is I can't post it as an answer. because I've asked the question today.
`$.ajaxSetup()` has something called `beforeSend` which has the deferred object passed to it! I can create an array and add the deferred object to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I've found a solution on this. `$.ajaxSetup()` has something called `beforeSend` which has the deferred object passed to it! I can create an array and add the deferred object to it.

```
var ajaxCalls = [{}];
        $.ajaxSetup($.ajaxSettings, {
            beforeSend: function (deferred) {

                ajaxCalls.push(deferred);
            },
            complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                if (ajaxCalls.length == 1) {
                    //Do Something...
                }
            }
        });
```